# Appgrid not working. Only shows empty window.

Tags: 13.04

I have installed Appgrid from ppa:appgrid/stable. When I run it, it just shows empty window.

When I run it with sudo, the same thing happens. It just keeps doing same thing in terminal .

[image: Terminal output]

I tried it both on saucy and raring (64 bit - Gnome version). Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by installing 'python3-gi-cairo' on Ubuntu 12.10, 13.04, 13.10 and 14.04 , or by installing 'python-gi-cairo' on Ubuntu 12.04. This will be fixed in the next release of App Grid.